# How to write result to JSON files in gcs in Dataflow/Beam

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using the Python Beam SDK 0.6.0. And I would like to write my output to JSON in Google Cloud Storage. What is the best way to do this?

I quess I can use `WriteToText` from the Text IO sink but then I have to format each row separately, right? How do I save my result into valid JSON files that contain lists of objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, for reference, I solved this by writing my own sink building on the `_TextSink` used by `WriteToText` in the beam SDK.

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works well so far. Hope it might help someone else.

```
import os
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import coders
from apache_beam.io.iobase import Write
from apache_beam.transforms import PTransform   

class _JsonSink(beam.io.FileSink):
    """A Dataflow sink for writing JSON files."""

    def __init__(self,
                 file_path_prefix,
                 file_name_suffix='',
                 num_shards=0,
                 shard_name_template=None,
                 coder=coders.ToStringCoder(),
                 compression_type=beam.io.CompressionTypes.AUTO):

        super(_JsonSink, self).__init__(
            file_path_prefix,
            file_name_suffix=file_name_suffix,
            num_shards=num_shards,
            shard_name_template=shard_name_template,
            coder=coder,
            mime_type='text/plain',
            compression_type=compression_type)
        self.last_rows = dict()

    def open(self, temp_path):
        """ Open file and initialize it w opening a list."""
        file_handle = super(_JsonSink, self).open(temp_path)
        file_handle.write('[\n')
        return file_handle

    def write_record(self, file_handle, value):
        """Writes a single encoded record converted to JSON and terminates the
        line w a comma."""
        if self.last_rows.get(file_handle, None) is not None:
            file_handle.write(self.coder.encode(
                json.dumps(self.last_rows[file_handle])))
            file_handle.write(',\n')

        self.last_rows[file_handle] = value

    def close(self, file_handle):
        """Finalize the JSON list and close the file handle returned from
        ``open()``. Called after all records are written.
        """
        if file_handle is not None:
            # Write last row without a comma
            file_handle.write(self.coder.encode(
                json.dumps(self.last_rows[file_handle])))

            # Close list and then the file
            file_handle.write('\n]\n')
            file_handle.close()


class WriteToJson(PTransform):
    """PTransform for writing to JSON files."""

    def __init__(self,
                 file_path_prefix,
                 file_name_suffix='',
                 num_shards=0,
                 shard_name_template=None,
                 coder=coders.ToStringCoder(),
                 compression_type=beam.io.CompressionTypes.AUTO):

        self._sink = _JsonSink(file_path_prefix, file_name_suffix, num_shards,
                               shard_name_template, coder, compression_type)

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return pcoll | Write(self._sink)
```

Using the sink is similar to how you use the the text sink:

```
pcol | WriteToJson('gs://path/to/file', file_name_suffix='.json')
```

Comment: It's been 3 years, but this answer helped a lot. Just don't understand `self.last_rows`. What's its purpose?

Answer (score 8):

Making each file contain a single list with a bunch of elements is difficult, because you'd need to group a bunch of elements and then write them together to a file. Let me advice you to use a different format.

You may consider the [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/examples/) format, where each line in a file represents a single JSON element.

Transforming your data to JSON Lines should be pretty easy. The following transform should do the trick:

```
class WriteToJsonLines(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self._file_name = file_name

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll
                | 'format json' >> beam.Map(json.dumps)
                | 'write to text' >> beam.WriteToText(self._file_name))
```

Finally, if you later on want to read your JSON Lines files, you can  write your own JsonLinesSource or use the one in [beam_utils](https://github.com/pabloem/beam_utils).

Comment: Let me know if your data isn't organized this way, and I'll try to figure out something that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I really need it to be JSON though. Wrote my own sink in the end that I think should work.

Comment: that's fair! ; )

Answer (score -1):

Although this is a year late, I'd like to add  another way to write a result to json files in GCS. For apache beam 2.x pipelines, this transform works:

> .withSuffix(".json")

For example:

```
result.apply("WriteToGCS", TextIO.write().to(bucket)
            .withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP)
            .withSuffix(".json")
            .withNumShards(chunks));
```

Comment: This looks like it's code for the Java SDK. I think the OP was looking for Python. As far as I know the Python SDK still doesn't have anything equivalent to this.